# Insert Multiple rows in a single column in mySql

Tags: mysql, insert, mysql-insert-id

I have a table called class in that I have three columns "Name", "Roll Number" and "Subject". Now the Name & Roll Number columns have 50 records each like

```
"Name"   "Roll Number"  "Subject" 
John       1              Null
Mark       4              Null 
Steeve     5              Null
Riya       2              Null
```

Now I want to insert data in the column, that is a different subject for different roll numbers like

"Roll Number"    "Subject"
1               Maths
4               Computers
5                Music
2                Biology

Comment: Are roll number unique to every name?

Comment: The roll number is unique for every student & I have 200 roll numbers (rows) to fill the subject.